# How to use Fleet Telematics with routing V8

Tags: here-api, here-fleet-telematics

In the API reference of Fleet Telematics it says you can use Here Routing V8 for calculate the route. But when I try to send a request (with origin, destination, transport and obviously the API Key) it always return error 404. Which is the correct way to use the fleettelematics/v8/routes then?

Here is a request make with Here Routing (I removed the API key for the picture):
[image: Here is a request make with Here Routing (I removed the API key for the picture)]

And this is the same request with Fleet Telematics:
[image: And this is the same request with Fleet Telematics]

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the query parameter "return=polyline".  So in your example it would be

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?apiKey={apiKey}&transportMode=truck&origin=52.51375,13.42462&destination=52.52332,13.42&return=polyline
```

I'm still learning to migrate from v7 to v8 myself, but I figure we could do work this out together, so keep this thread updated if you work it out

Comment: With router.hereapi works fine, but i want to do it with fleet.Is.Hereapi for getting the tolls in the route, but even adding the return parameters I still getting error 404.

Comment: @chris does it return the cost-optimized route? if yes, what parameters you are using to get the cost-optimized route?

Answer (score 0):

Fleet Telematics API compiles your changes into routable binary map format. Routing uses these layers on top of the HERE map layers.

Documentation page:
https://developers.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/topics/custom-routes.html

also, please review the following example for custom routing using fleet telematics

```
http://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/overlays/upload.json?map_name=OVERLAYEXAMPLE1
&amp;overlay_spec=[
  { "op":"override",
    "shape":[[50.10765,8.68774],[50.10914,8.68771]],
    "layer":"LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCN",
    "data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"0"}
  },
  { "op":"create",
    "shape":[[50.10937,8.68422],[50.10807,8.68525],[50.10737,8.68387]],
    "data":{"NAMES":"ENGBNDemo Road"}
  },
  { "op":"override",
    "shape":[[50.10937,8.68422],[50.10807,8.68525],[50.10737,8.68387]],
    "layer":"TRUCK_RESTR_FCN",
    "data":{"VEHICLE_TYPES":"truck", "WEIGHT_RESTRICTION":"3300"}
  }
]
&amp;storage=readonly
&amp;app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&amp;app_code=YOUR_APP_CODE
```